# Here API states that I cannot store results. So how can I use it for address validation/completion?

Tags: geolocation, geospatial, geocoding, here-api

I've been testing out the Freemium HERE API and just had a deeper look at the FAQs and Docs.

From the [pricing plan page](https://developer.here.com/pricing#freemium--pro-plans), it states the following:

> Storing results from geocodes is not allowed for Location Services products

So how can this API possibly be used for address validation / completion? For example, a user enters a misspelled address / zipcode into a web form on my online store. I now have a dirty customer record. Am I prohibited from using the API to autocorrect the address? e.g. from `12 Main Street, Nwe Yrk` to `12 Main Street, New York, 90210`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, one of the purposes of the geocoder autocomplete API is to autocorrect addresses:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder-autocomplete/topics/quick-start-get-suggestions.html.

You can readily use this API in your web form to get address suggestions while the user types. In this case the user always enters/chooses the right address and you are of course free to store this in your database. What you are not allowed to do is to store the whole response/results (detailed map information about locations in the response or in the case of batch geocoder, the results zip file) for offline use.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't have autocomplete set up yet on the webform and it will be a while until it's set up. I would like to correct the address **after** they have entered it using the geocoder API. Are you saying this is not possible under any sort of plan whatsoever?

Comment: We have discussed your case and it is allowed so you can proceed. In case you would like to store the entire response/results for later offline use then you would need to contact our sales team for a different plan (See updated answer).

Comment: That's great, thank you. I definitely do not need the entire API response, maybe just 2% of it i.e. a missing county that the user failed to enter. Last question: I noticed there is long/lat in the response. Can I append that to customer data also?

Comment: Yes, you can append that.