# Here API states that I cannot store results, but we even we only need city and district?

Tags: here-api

I am reading API Policies and have some questions.

We are working on a social networking app and need to access user location. Whenever users publish a post, system will show users location on the NewsFeed, our system will not store the complete data, but only City and district.

we are surveying here-api,opencage and Mapbox.

for here solution, I found a discussion on similar use case, and it seems to be answer by here suppose engineer, just wondering if we could implement the same method?

[Here API states that I cannot store results. So how can I use it for address validation/completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58278228/here-api-states-that-i-cannot-store-results-so-how-can-i-use-it-for-address-val)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's possible, for example, if you have GPS data like lat/long. Then You can use this reverse-geocode API to get the cities and districts.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-reverse-geocode-brief.html